# Os permission error when trying to create a `tun` device

Tags: networking, rust, network-programming, tun, tun-tap

I'm trying to create a tun device with rust's `tun_tap` create, I'm following documentation and trying to create an interface with the `tun_tap::Iface::new(..);`, but I'm getting the error below.

```sh
Error: Os { code: 1, kind: PermissionDenied, message: "Operation not permitted" }
```

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 Lts version on this machine,
How can I run this code without giving it root permission? Is this anything that I can do
with the code or with Linux permission itself?
any ideas would be appreciated ;)

Comment: I think you don't actually need root but `CAP_NET_ADMIN`, if that is acceptable. Try with `setcap cap_net_admin+ep binaryprogram` after compiling.

Comment: Maybe this will help you https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/557306/how-to-allow-non-root-user-to-create-tun-devices.